# Flex/Actionscript : passing data from custom class to main application?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, scope

Ok this probably sounds dumb but Im a complete beginner in Flex programming.

I have an application with a main .mxml file, and a certain class Foo that I call from the .mxml

In Foo, I make a URLRequest and listen for the Complete event. Then I found myself with the returned data in a Foo function, but I have no idea how to communicate it to the .mxml part of the applicaton ! I looked into ArrayCollections but I can't seem to understand how they work and whether it might help. Isn't there a way to modify, from inside the class, a variable with a global scope ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a small application, but if it's a large application you might want to look at a micro-framework like [RobotLegs](http://www.robotlegs.org/)

If you have your Foo class extend EventDispatcher then it will be able to send events and have the main MXML app listen for said events.

```
package com.example
{
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
    import com.example.events.MyEvent;

    public class Foo extends EventDispatcher 
    {
        public function doAction():void 
        {
            var someData:String = "blah";
            dispatchEvent(new MyEvent(MyEvent.SOMETHING_HAPPENED, someData));
        }
    }
}
```

A Custom event with a payload (in this case a string)

```
package com.example.events 
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class MyEvent extends Event 
    {
        static public const SOMETHING_HAPPENED:String = "somethingHappened";

        private var _myData:String;

        public function get myData():String 
        {
            return _myData;
        }

        public function MyEvent(type:String, myData:String, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false) 
        {
            _myData = myData;
            super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
        }

        override public function clone():Event 
        {
            return new MyEvent(type, myData, bubbles, cancelable);
        }
    }
}
```

Working with your Foo class from the main file:

```
public function EventDispatcherExample() {
    var foo:Foo = new Foo();
    foo.addEventListener(MyEvent.SOMETHING_HAPPENED, actionHandler);
    foo.doAction();
}

private function actionHandler(e:MyEvent):void {
    trace("my data is: " + e.myData);
}
```

Comment: ok so Im able to catch the event but how do I attach a variable to this event ^^ ?

Comment: erm so when does Foo pass a value to the event ?

Comment: OK got it, Flex is expecting two arguments anyway when instantiating MyEvent

Comment: The value (the 'someData' var above) gets passed as the second argument of when create the new MyEvent as the argument of dispatchEvent... dispatchEvent(new MyEvent(MyEvent.SOMETHING_HAPPENED, someData));

Comment: beat me to it :)

Yes, that's the benefit of creating a custom event, the payload is required and it type checks it as well so you can't pass the wrong thing in by mistake.

Comment: thanks again, hope I will be able to make it up to you someday in SQL or javascript ^^ who knows

Answer (score 1):

```
import mx.core.FlexGlobals;
FlexGlobals.toplevelApplication.varName;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Foo class can dispatch an event and have something in you main.mxml listen for that event. I am sure that I could create an example. I think it is under customer events in Flex documentation. This is assuming I understand the question.

Comment: The DispatchEvent won't work inside the class, no matter which package I import ! But it works in the main .mxml though

Answer (score 1):

As John said, an event is your best choice.

If you'd like some example code, I provided some for a similar question here: [Data from Popup to Main Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911537/send-data-from-popup-to-main-application/6911838#6911838)

Answer (score 0):

An event might be the best way to do it as it has been stated.
Another approach is to dispatch an event like this

```
dispatchEvent(new Event('somethingHappened'));
```

and also create a get method in your class for the data you need to get.

Then all you have to do in your main app is this

```
var foo:Foo = new Foo();
foo.addEventListener('somethingHappened', actionHandler);

private function actionHandler(e:Event):void 
{
    trace(foo.memberData);
}
```

This way might be more suitable if the data should be a class member anyway and if you would like to avoid creating a new event class.

Comment: ok but Foo still should extend the DispatchEvent class, right ? Because the `dispatchEvent` line would occur within the Foo class you knoew